# Can cookie be used in VS Code Webview API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to integrate a web application inside VS Code using the Webview API.
I have this kind of error mentioning that cookies cannot be read:

```
error: any
:
DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs. at HttpXsrfCookieExtractor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfCookieExtractor.getToken (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:7688:37) at ApiXsrfInterceptor.push../src/app/lib/atlasmap-data-mapper/services/api-xsrf-interceptor.service.ts.ApiXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http://127.0.0.1:8585/main.js:8780:45) at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:7129:33) at HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:7720:25) at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:7129:33) at HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:7764:27) at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:6969:184) at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:106781:27) at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:106771:18) at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:101228:18)
code
:
18
message
:
"Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs."
name
:
"SecurityError"
stack
:
"Error: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs.↵    at HttpXsrfCookieExtractor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfCookieExtractor.getToken (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:7688:37)↵    at ApiXsrfInterceptor.push../src/app/lib/atlasmap-data-mapper/services/api-xsrf-interceptor.service.ts.ApiXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http://127.0.0.1:8585/main.js:8780:45)↵    at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:7129:33)↵    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:7720:25)↵    at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:7129:33)↵    at HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:7764:27)↵    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:6969:184)↵    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:106781:27)↵    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:106771:18)↵    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (http://127.0.0.1:8585/vendor.js:101228:18)"
```

is it a restriction of VS Code Webview API? Is it something to configure?

for reference, the project that i try to integrate is https://github.com/atlasmap/atlasmap, there is a [PR](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/vscode-atlasmap/pull/9) with "current state" (aka not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode webview API's have disabled assess to localstorage and cookies as well, that's the reason you getting error.

This issue talks about it https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48464